# jQuery - Animated Collapsible DIV, sliding up?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this jQuery script to animate a div to open/close when the user clicks a button: 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm

Is there any way to make it slide up, instead of down?

What I mean is: Instead of the DIV opening downwards (extending the area below it), is it possible for it to extend the content on top of it, so that it doesnt extend downwards?

Blarh, I'm finding it hard to describe.

Example:

```
Before:
1###TOP OF PAGE###
2#################
3#################
4#################
5#################
6######BUTTON#####
7###HIDDEN DIV####
8##BOTTOM OF PAGE#

After:
1###TOP OF PAGE###
2#################
3######BUTTON#####
4#####OPEN DIV####
5####CONTENT######
6####CONTENT######
7####CONTENT######
8##BOTTOM OF PAGE#

Instead of like this, as default:
1###TOP OF PAGE###
2#################
3#################
4#################
5#################
6######BUTTON#####
7#####OPEN DIV####
8####CONTENT######
9####CONTENT######
10###CONTENT######
11#BOTTOM OF PAGE#
```

Sorry for my crappy explanation, but I hope you understand :P

Thanks!

Comment: checkout the example I posted, and if that is not what you mean please explain it more

Comment: good explain :) the one solution is change the top property of div when slide to open,so when its slide down ,top property change and get the div to up. very Simple solution Maybe!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [JQuery slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) to hide an element or [JQuery slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) to display an element 
 also you can use [JQuery slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to toggle the element

and this is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kYyAA/5/)

Comment: Sorry. The function works, and it is hiding/unhiding by sliding up/down the div. But, I want the div to open upwards. So that the button will slide up, and the content will be shown from where the button was, and upwards. Default is: when you click the button, the div opens downwards. Does this make more sense? Sorry =/

Comment: Say you have this div (hidden, with the content) and a button to trigger the show/hide effect, alligned to the bottom of another wrapping div. When you click the button to open the div, I want the content above to move up to make room for the div, not the div to extend out of the wrapping divs limits (downwards, overlapping content below)...

Comment: If you check out example 5 on the page I posted, you can see what kind of effect I want. When you click example 4 first, then example 5 toggle button, the button and content goes upwards, not downwards as with the other examples. (Example 5 is a group. I only use 1, so no groups for me)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at explaining. If you look at your example now. When you click "Show", the green box slides down to reveal the red box. What I want, is for the green box to stay where it is, and the blue box to become smaller to give room for the expanding red box.
(obviously, there has to be room for this. But I've left room for it to expand, without breaking the content above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14123/discussion-between-ayman-jitan-and-stian-berg-larsen)