# Expand DIV vertically by keeping the footer at the same position when open/hide element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that is shown/hide by clicking a button as shown on the image below. At here, when pressing the button, I want the the button at the same position and expand the div (content) above it (towards to the top - position 1 instead of the bottom - position 2). I tried with the `position:absolute;` properties but nothing has changed. Any idea?

Here is the sample html just for indicating this layout:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
//Content...
</div>

<div id=hidden>
//Hiddent area...
</div>

<input type="button">

<footer>
//Footer...
</footer>
</body>
```

[image]

**Update:**

Here is the second behaviour for the second sample: I want the code works as explained.

[image]

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Maybe an example (http://jsfiddle.net) would help ! :)

Comment: Can't you see the image displayed above?

Comment: We do see the image, we need to know what you've done so far, and we need code to check what's wrong... css, html, ... paste an example at http://jsfiddle.net and it will be really easier to help!

Comment: Dude share the code on JSFIDDLE

Comment: As I used many different css files and the layout and view pages are very complex, I just wanted to know on the sample layout above. You can give your samples according to the layout code and then I will try to apply it to my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may need `position: fixed;` and not `position: absolute;`. Does this work?

```js
$(function () {
  $(".expcol").hide();
  $("#btnCM").click(function () {
    $(".expcol").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */

footer {position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <button id="btnCM">Click Me</button>
  <div class="expcol">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione commodi, tenetur laborum et beatae praesentium animi, repellat cum pariatur nostrum harum hic excepturi cumque, magnam illo neque quam molestias nam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet asperiores sunt sed nemo dignissimos enim tempora quam recusandae cum debitis provident eaque dicta illum, voluptatum expedita rerum vel cupiditate deleniti.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Or if the button is on the bottom:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".expcol").hide();
  $("#btnCM").click(function () {
    $(".expcol").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */

footer {position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <div class="expcol">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione commodi, tenetur laborum et beatae praesentium animi, repellat cum pariatur nostrum harum hic excepturi cumque, magnam illo neque quam molestias nam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet asperiores sunt sed nemo dignissimos enim tempora quam recusandae cum debitis provident eaque dicta illum, voluptatum expedita rerum vel cupiditate deleniti.</p>
  </div>
  <button id="btnCM">Click Me</button>
</footer>
```

Comment: Both of the examples are perfect, perfect, perfect :) @Other Dudes : As it can be seen from Praveen Kumar's answer, there is no need me to post the whole code in the question. Many thanks for your answer. Voted+++

Comment: Just one more question regarding to **sample 2** : Assume that there is a content `<div>` above the `<footer>`. "What changes should be made if we want the `<div>` expand to the top when clicking the button? For this sample the `<footer>` comes above the  `<div>` and if there is some content in the div, it goes behind the expanded area. Could you also post the 3rd sample please? Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to understand. Can you clarify again?

Comment: Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/spypph92/) jsfiddle. When clicking "Click Me" the footer expands and comes above the content. Whereas I want the content expands with the footer ans a scrollbar is displayed.  What changes should be made? Could you pls update jsfiddle and post here?

Comment: In the right side of the div. I also tried `overflow-y: auto;` but does not make any sense :(

Comment: I am really unable to understand the question. Set a fixed `height` and `overflow: auto;` if you want the scrollbars to appear.

Comment: I also want the bottom of the div goes towards to top with the footer as if they are stuck.

Comment: If you have a look at [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spypph92/), and click "Click Me", the footer expands, but the bottom of the content remains under the footer and not seen. So, I just want to show also this area (bottom of the content) and want the div content goes to the top. Is it clear?

Comment: Thanks, but I want the bottom of the div comes with the footer as sticked with it. Is it possible to do this just by setting css?

Comment: Now I really don't understand. `:(`

Comment: Sorry, I added a new image explaining it to the question. If there is anything that is not understood please do not hesitate to ask again. Thanks.

Comment: @Christof That looks like accordion

Comment: Yes, any idea for this issue?

Comment: Yesss, it is :) Ok, I have found lots of samples as on http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php Many thanks for your kind helps.

Comment: There is also another good sample using jQuery.slideUp on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kYyAA/5/) page for [jQuery - Animated Collapsible DIV, sliding up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556667/jquery-animated-collapsible-div-sliding-up) question. It maybe useful for somebody who look for such a kind of problem.

Comment: Great buddy. Sorry was not available after that as my timezone made me to sleep! `:)`

Comment: Never mind, I know that I would not have found the solution without your help :) Thanks...